# Change identity of a TFS build agent

Tags: tfs, service, networking, identity

We have a TFS build agent that runs integration tests. Some of these tests make calls to web services on the Internet.

Our network uses a proxy to talk to the Internet.

Since the build agent runs under the identity on Network Service and the settings of Network Service are not configured to use the proxy, the tests fail.

How do I do one of the following?

- Change the identity of the build agent to a domain account
- Configure Network Service to use the proxy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To change the identity of the build agent you just go into Windows Services and change the identity of the TFSBuild service (service name is "Visual Studio Team Foundation Build").

Comment: Thanks, name of the service was "Visual Studio Team Foundation Build"

Comment: The docs about deploying a TFS Build agent warns about not changing the user directly from the services snap-in but rather using the command. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v1-windows)

Comment: Same for a VSTS agent. The service name is 'VSTS Agent'

Comment: ***How*** do you actually change the identity?

Comment: For 2019 the name of the service is Azure Devops agent.