# npm run script error: Failed to exec generateservertestreport script

Tags: node.js, npm, tfs

I see this issue when I run npm script through tfs build but when I run the above directly tfs build machine I don't see any error.

**Note: I use node -v 8.12.0 and npm -v 6.4.1**

I tried to find the reason for this error I didn't find resource explaining me the reason for this error

```
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\cygwin64\home\licbuild\ANSYSDev\LicensingPortal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\cygwin64\home\licbuild\ANSYSDev\LicensingPortal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to run the script through TFS build machine directly but failed through TFS build.

This may caused by permission of your build service account such as local Admin. You may use a different account to remote build machine and run the script other than your build service account.

To narrow down the issue, you could also use build service account directly login your build machine and try to run the script again if still get same result.

Besides, you could also set `system.debug=true` to get a more detail build log for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks PatrickLu-MSFT , How to set system.debug=true. or How do I login to the machine as 'Network Service'

Comment: Also I have added 'Network Service' under ' Computer Management > Administrators' group. Under which the username with which I can run the build is part of

Comment: @karansys To set  `system.debug=true`, you just need to add a variable in your build pipeline. Sample Blog: [Enable Verbose Debug Mode for TFS Build vNext](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) Instead of using  'Network Service', you could use another user, such as the one which you can run the build. To do this please refer this doc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171927/change-identity-of-a-tfs-build-agent

Comment: Hi @karansys Any update on this issue? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Hi PatrickLu-MSFT, I gave a try on this, I did have permisssion issue, which was solved following your instruction, thanks